# Passing dataType as json failing to execute

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am trying to perform the below SQL query on page load via JQuery/AJAX. It will not post when I write `dataType: 'json',` and does not provide an error in the console log.

I have tested the SQL is executing by placing a echo statement. Without the line it echos, with the line it does not.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Load Questions
    var getQuestions= true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "comment.php",
        context: document.body,
        data:{getQuestions:getQuestions},
        dataType: 'json', //<--This line here
        success: function(data){
            $("#updateDisplay").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

SQL (comment.php)

```
<?php
    //connect to db
    include 'connect.php';
    $getQuestions = $_POST['getQuestions'];;
    if($getQuestions==TRUE){
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * 
        FROM Questions 
        ORDER BY QuestionID DESC";
    $runQuery = mysql_query($sqlQuery) or die(mysql_error());
    echo 'Test echo';
    echo json_encode($runQuery);
}
```

After the  I have a DIV to place the results:

```
<div id="updateDisplay">
//PHP loop will go here
```

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: Ah yes I do, didn't know how to see that before thanks.
Error is: 
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: getQuestions is not defined ReferenceError: getQuestions is not defined

Error is only present if I add the section above where I wrote "I tried to add"

Without it no error

If I declare it pre-the ajax call I get no error, ill update above since comments dont support formatting

Comment: And now you're well on your way to solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't correctly handling the SQL output to match JSON.

Fixed SQL

```
$runQueryArray=array();
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * 
FROM Questions 
ORDER BY QuestionID DESC";
$runQuery = mysql_query($sqlQuery) or die(mysql_error());
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($runQuery, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){
    $runQueryArray[] = $row;
}
    echo json_encode($runQueryArray);
}
```

Also needed to fix my JSON call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getQuestions= true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "comment.php",
        context: document.body,
        data:{getQuestions:getQuestions},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(JSON){
            $.each(JSON,function(i,val){
                $('#updateDisplay').append('<p>QuestionID: '+ val.QuestionID + ' Title: '+ val.Title+ ' Description: '+ val.Description+' Date Created: '+val.DateCreated+'</p><p><button type="submit" class="postReply" value='+val.QuestionID+'>Reply</button></p>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```